# i have problems in this code and i get yes in the all answer

Tags: java, string

> Write a program that, when given a String `s` and a char `c`, prints out ‘yes’ if `c` 
>   exists in `s`. Otherwise prints out ‘no’. (You are expected to do it using loops. You 
>   can use only length() and charAt() functions of String type.)

**Examples:**

```
 south u --> yes 
 north T --> no
```

Output should look exactly like this:

```
 >Please enter a string: 
 >ahmet
 >Please enter a char: 
 >m
 >yes
```

---

I tried to implement it, but I don't know what is the problem in my code. I always get "true".
In my implementation I used an integer that can be 0 or 1. 
If it is 0 I print false. 
If it's 1 I print true.

This is my code:

```
package ass32;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ass33 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);          
       System.out.println("give me any string :  ");           
       String name = in.next();
       System.out.println(">Please enter a char: ");               
       char c = in.next().charAt(0);
       int  e = 0 ;
       int t = name.length();
       char f ; 
       char s ; 
       for ( int i = 0 ; i <t ; i++) {
           f = name.charAt(i);           
           for ( int j = 0 ; j <t ; j++) {
               s = name.charAt(j);
               if (s==f)
                   e = 1 ;             
           }
      }

     if (e==1 )
         System.out.println("yes");          
     else if (e==0 )
         System.out.println("no");
  }     
}
```

Comment: Thats Java Code and not C or C++!

Comment: Because e will be 1 always! Why do you have two loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing all the characters of the String against all the characters of the same String, so of course you find a match and return "yes". You only need a single loop.

All you need is :

```
e = 0;
for ( int i = 0 ; i <t ; i++) {    
    f = name.charAt(i);
    if (f==c) {
        e = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    f = name.charAt(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < t; j++) { // Remove this loop
        s = name.charAt(j); // Remove this also
        if (s == f) { // Change this to (c==f)
            e = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
boolean isCharFound = false;
for ( int i = 0 ; i <t ; i++) {    
    f = name.charAt(i);
    if (f==c) {
       isCharFound = true;
       break;
    }
}
```

- You are using two loops with same string, So if your string is "abc", you are comparing abc with abc hence you always see sat char a in same string abc present. So that's the bug.
- Another way to improve your code is you should use boolean instead of integer for whether you find the character in string or not.